# OSX keyboard shortcut background application, how to

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, backgroundworker

I want my OSX application to sit in the background and wait for a keyboard shortcut to go into action. It should be configurable similar to Growl in the preferences, or accessible as dropbox in the statusbar.

- What kind of xcode template do I have to use?
- How do I capture keyboard shortcuts globally?

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at Dave DeLong's [DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey) class on GitHub.

> DDHotKey is an easy-to-use Cocoa class for registering an application to respond to system key events, or "hotkeys".
>
> A global hotkey is a key combination that always executes a specific action, regardless of which app is frontmost. For example, the Mac OS X default hotkey of "command-space" shows the Spotlight search bar, even if Finder is not the frontmost application.

A generous licence as well.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to access it in preferences, use the Preference Pane template. If you want it in the status bar, create a normal application, set the LSUIElement key to 1 in Info.plist, and use NSStatusItem to create the item.

To capture shortcuts globally, you need to include the Carbon framework also. Use `RegisterEventHotKey` and `UnregisterEventHotKey` to register for the events.

```
OSStatus HotKeyEventHandlerProc(EventHandlerCallRef inCallRef, EventRef ev, void* inUserData) {
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    if(GetEventKind(ev) == kEventHotKeyPressed) {
        [(id)inUserData handleKeyPress];
    } else if(GetEventKind(ev) == kEventHotKeyReleased) {
        [(id)inUserData handleKeyRelease];
    } else err = eventNotHandledErr;
    return err;
}

//EventHotKeyRef hotKey; instance variable

- (void)installEventHandler {
    static BOOL installed = NO;
    if(installed) return;
    installed = YES;
    const EventTypeSpec hotKeyEvents[] = {{kEventClassKeyboard,kEventHotKeyPressed},{kEventClassKeyboard,kEventHotKeyReleased}};
    InstallApplicationEventHandler(NewEventHandlerUPP(HotKeyEventHandlerProc),GetEventTypeCount(hotKeyEvents),hotKeyEvents,(void*)self,NULL);
}

- (void)registerHotKey {
    [self installEventHandler];
    UInt32 virtualKeyCode = ?; //The virtual key code for the key
    UInt32 modifiers = cmdKey|shiftKey|optionKey|controlKey; //remove the modifiers you don't want
    EventHotKeyID eventID = {'abcd','1234'}; //These can be any 4 character codes. It can be used to identify which key was pressed
    RegisterEventHotKey(virtualKeyCode,modifiers,eventID,GetApplicationEventTarget(),0,(EventHotKeyRef*)&hotKey);
}
- (void)unregisterHotKey {
    if(hotkey) UnregisterEventHotKey(hotKey);
    hotKey = 0;
}

- (void)handleHotKeyPress {
    //handle key press
}
- (void)handleHotKeyRelease {
    //handle key release
}
```