# Register a global hotkey without support for assistive devices enabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

Using this code, I may register a global event handler:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: NSKeyDownMask 
                                       handler: ^(NSEvent *incomingEvent) {

           NSString *chars = [[incomingEvent characters] lowercaseString];
           unichar character = [chars characterAtIndex:0];    

           // do something useful
           NSLog(@"keydown globally! Which key? This key: %c", character);

        }];
```

Unfortunately, events get passed along to this monitor, if **support for assistive devices** is enabled. Without assistive devices being enabled, no events get passed along.

Form the documentation:

```
Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled or if your 
application is trusted for accessibility access (see AXIsProcessTrusted).
```

**I wonder, if another method exists, which passes along events without forcing the user to enable specific features of OS X.**

While I didn't find a solution in Apple's docs, a solution must exist. E.g. the MAS-downloaded version of Alfred allows to define a hotkey.

Interestingly, Alfred's preferences only shows **special keys** and points out, that **certain special key combinations may not work**.

Since I basically want to show / hide a 'global' non-activating panel, I probably should simply prepare a system service. Should I?

Comment: You could use the old Carbon function `RegisterEventHotKey`. I'm pretty sure it's deprecated, but it still works well and doesn't require assistive access (and is still used in some of Apple's example code). It will not allow you to override system commands, though. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640190/458390) for example code.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: `RegisterEventHotKey` is not marked deprecated as of the 10.7 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try creating a Quartz Event Tap, with `kCGSessionEventTap` as the location.

[*Quartz Event Services Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html)
[Sample code from *Mac OS X Internals*](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503003001/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/)

Comment: Thx! Comment in the mentioned sample code: You need superuser privileges to create the event tap, unless accessibility is enabled. To do so, select the "Enable access for assistive devices" checkbox in the Universal Access system preference pane.

Comment: I think that's only necessary if you specify `kCGHIDEventTap`.  Maybe you could try it out and report back with the result.

Comment: Called it from (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:aNotification. CGEventTapCreate fails and prints 'failed to create event tap'.

Comment: Hi there @Rob I was trying to do this too with no assistance. There seems to be some confusion in the comments, can you please verify if it works globaly or not for sure? I posted topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32299785/1828637