# Hotkey when no assistance enabled CGEventTap

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

I had used `addLocal` and it would work in my application, but I want to watch globally so i tried `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` but `NSEventKeyDown` is not getting triggered at all. Apparently it needs assistive permission enabled.

I am able to watch NSScrollWheel events globally. Which is interesting.

Before I put a bunch of time into and come to same roadblock I was hoping to ask first, would using `CGEventTap` to monitor key events work globally without assitive turned on?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventTapLocation

I will also explore other methods but was very curious (for learning) about if CGEventTap will work globally no problems. He seems to hint here that it may work but the comments show some confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9345536/1828637

Other methods I am going to use also Carbon APIs.

Comment: Yes, I think CGEventTap should work without any additional permissions. I'm using this method for kCGEventLeftMouseDown in my sandboxed project and all works fine. I think it should work for kCGEventKeyDown too.

Comment: Thank you @comrade I'll start working on it, it will take me a bit of time/days as I have to decalre everything in ctypes, so if anyone else knows for sure please share. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `CGEventTap` requires the same access for assistive devices permissions as a global event monitor. From the documentation for `CGEventTapCreate()`:

> Event taps receive key up and key down events if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The current process is running as the root user.
> - Access for assistive devices is enabled. In OS X v10.4, you can enable this feature using System Preferences, Universal Access panel,
>     Keyboard view.

I recommend using the old Carbon `RegisterEventHotKey()` mechanism. It still isn't deprecated and is available for 64-bit. This is in contrast to much of Carbon. Basically, Apple recognizes that there's no proper replacement, yet.

Comment: Ah thanks Ken you saved me wasting a lot of my time. I'll go with this approach then. :) There is no way to temporarily set it to assitive programtically huh? Is it progmatically possible to open up the "grant assitive permission", so its very easy users to add, most of my users are newbies cant handle this level of stuff.

Comment: Granting access to assistive devices has changed since that documentation I quoted above. It is no longer globally on or globally off. It's granted on a per-application basis based on the application's bundle ID and code signature. An app calls `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions()` with a dictionary mapping `kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt` to `kCFBooleanTrue` to cause a secure prompt asking the user if they trust the app. If the user does, they can grant access to that specific app. This is 10.9+ API. You're probably using this from a plug-in, which complicates matters.

Comment: Ah that is ok that's perfect for a request for permission. And for <10.9 there was programtic way to grant yourself trust isnt there, I think it was [`AXMakeProcessTrusted`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXMakeProcessTrusted) is this correct? I'll definitely use the Carbon API for hotkey, but for learning this will be very fun. There is no automatic make trusted for 10.9+ is there?

Comment: Ah a nasty note on MakeTrusted: `the caller should relaunch the process after this function returns successfully for the trusted status to take effect. `, which ill have to tell the user to restart, small annoyance. Would be ideal if there was a restartless way.

Comment: A process has to have root privileges to use `AXMakeProcessTrusted()`. Of what use would a privacy/security feature be if an app could simply make itself trusted? There's a reason you can't do these things without the user's permission.

Comment: Thanks @Ken I realize yeah thats a good point I realize these things can now be used for key loggers. I don't have an evil mind so I dont realize it at first hahaha number 1 on my mind is to make things work for my users without having them to do more then install the addon :)

Comment: Hey @Ken by any chance do you know if CGEventTapCreate requires to be on main thread?

Comment: It does not, but it has to be scheduled on some thread's run loop and that thread has to run its run loop.

Comment: Ahhh sweetness here i go diving into it! Thanks Ken!!

Comment: Oh but just to make sure, `addLocalMonitorForMakser:handler:` requires to be on main thread right?

Comment: Hey @Ken I've been working on this for the last couple of days but I can't seem to get the loop to recognize that I added a source to it, may you please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33209518/1828637

Comment: Hi there @Ken I was setting up a hotkey now and it seems I was having to use `InstallApplicationEventHandler` along with register hotkey, is this the correct approach? I got the question because `InstallApplicationEventHandler` is not in the docs on apple :(

Comment: Yes, it's the correct approach. `InstallApplicationEventHandler()` is a wrapper around [`InstallEventHandler()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/InstallEventHandler). See the Carbon Event Manager docs in the [Retired Documents Library](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/). Also, the related [guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon_Event_Manager/Intro/CarbonEventsIntro.html).

Comment: Ah thank you so much for that! I am defining InstallEventHandler now and then I will use that with `GetApplicationEventTarget` thank you sir!

Comment: Hey there @Ken I got it registering with no crash! But its not catching it, do i have to run an event loop? This is my code to register which doesnt crash - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L272-L289

Comment: Ah I'm doing some more reading and I'm thinking I use `WaitNextEvent` and `HandleEvent`?

Comment: Hey sir I asked the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879162/registereventhotkey-from-thread