# How does Alfred capture the Alt-Space keyboard command without "assistive device" access?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, alfred

[Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) for OS X is able to capture the keyboard presses `Alt+Space`, which it uses as a "Toggle Alfred" command. It captures this even when it is not the active/key window. [This question about "detecting system-wide `keyDown` events"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events) tells me that there are multiple methods for achieving this, but all require "assistive device" access. Alfred does not appear to have this access, so it must be using a different method.

How does Alfred achieve this? What API is it using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX keyboard shortcut background application, how to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639244/osx-keyboard-shortcut-background-application-how-to)